# not able to convert multidimentional list to a sentence using python

Tags: python, list, random, list-comprehension

```
import random
p = ['hello','hey','hi'],['brother','bro','sir'],['me','myself'],['a'],['hero']
print(random.choices(random.choices(p)))
```

**Desired output :**
hello bro myself a hero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import itertools
import random
' '.join(list(itertools.chain(*list(map(random.choices, p))))) 

# 'hey bro me a hero'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `random.choice`not `random.choices`

```
import random
p = ['hello','hey','hi'],['brother','bro','sir'],['me','myself'],['a'],['hero']
selection = [random.choice(x) for x in p]
output = ' '.join(selection)
print(output)
# "hello bro myself a hero" (or something else, it's random)
```

Comment: @cs95 I intentionally chose `selection` to be a generator, not a list comprehension.

Comment: [It's a little faster to pass `str.join` a list.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/4909087)

Comment: @cs95 Please re-add your answer, instead of modifying mine to look like yours. Also, I usually pass the generator expression to `join` directly, but I also intentionally made the code more verbose so the OP can more easily understand the steps.

Comment: I didn't want to because you beat me to the punch and a difference of braces isn't enough of a reason for a separate answer.

Comment: @cs95 OK, fair enough. Thank you for the hint about the performance.